# How to schedule a wall post with php and cUrl

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I managed to post a status to my wall with a custom app, but what I want to do, is schedule the status, to be posted on a given datetime.

The problem was, when I close my app, the script is aborted.
Right now it works, I'm using ignore_user_abort(true) and sleep().

I'm also using set_time_limit(1), once the given datetime has passed, so the script stops.

I feel like this is crappy coding and want to know if there's a better way to do this?

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
<?php
 ignore_user_abort(true);
 $token=$_GET["access_token"];
 $attachment =  array(
    'access_token' => "$token",
    'message' => "deze post moet om 14.14 online komen",
    'name' => "testpost",
    'link' => "http://myurl.be/",
    'description' => "Write here your description",
    'picture'=> "http://myurl/assets/images/layout/logo.png");

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Belgrade');
$time= date('d/m/Y H:i');
if ("10/01/2012 14:14" < $time ){
set_time_limit(1);
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);
}else{
sleep(60);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.myurl.com/tests/facebooklogin/post.php?access_token=".$token);
curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
}  
print $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store all the information needed for your post (text, link, description and so on) in a database (like MySQL), setup a PHP script that get's called periodically by cron and fetches all posts from the database that need to be posted by the time the script get's executed.

But be aware that access tokens expire after a few hours/a day or when the user changes his password. Unless you don't have a "offline_access" permission, then the token never expires.

Comment: I have a current production app that does just what Bjorn writes here.  This is your answer.  However, even though a user access token expires, Facebook has a "fix" for it.  They say to use the app access token if you've requested publish_stream permissions.  However, if a user changes their password, then they will need to reauth your app.

Comment: And where do you store the access token, in the session? Because I don't really get how I can run a script with cron, with a parameter.

Comment: We don't have `offline_access` permission anymore, then how can I send a post after the token has expired? There is a way to do that?

Comment: @GustavoStraube No, you can schedule an email to yourself if an access token has expired so you can know to re-login and get a fresh token.